# Past Lightning (weather) data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, weather

I am looking for data about lightning for the state of Colorado. I'd like to get them in geospatial data.

I want to display them in point showing them each county especially up in the mountains.

I am aware that the NWS in Pueblo has their map showing each county in percent numbers but that does not provide us information about each lighting strike..

Comment: Google "real-time lightning" (no quotes), visit https://lightning.nsstc.nasa.gov/data/data_lis.html and https://weather.msfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sportPublishData.pl?dataset=goes16glm&product=group&loc=conus and https://www.goes-r.gov/products/baseline-lightning-detection.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that 'Convective available potential energy' has a very strong correlation with lightning probability. This data you can get [here](http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc/) at 6 hour intervals worldwide since 1979.