# Data on Lightning Times and Location

Tags: geospatial, weather

I am looking for data on lighting strikes, time and location between 2014 and 2015.

There is a similar [request regarding lighting densities in colorado](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/past-lightning-weather-data). I'd need worldwide (or at least Africa-wide) coverage of ideally at lasst 2014 and 2015. There are multiple potential data sets, (an [overview is found here](https://ghrc.nsstc.nasa.gov/home/micro-articles/lightning)) such as the WLLN, however I was not able to find any openly accessible version of these data.

Comment: I accidentally commented on the linked question, but the comment should be helpful here too